How to get a list of all images required for StackGres?
I am preparing to set up StackGres in an air-gapped environment and need to pull all necessary images to my local repository. Could someone provide a list of all images required for StackGres and what values needed to be changed in helm chart?
Any additional tips on ensuring that I have all dependencies covered would also be appreciated. I will be using sharded cluster.
Thank you!
